# Cannot output red/green/blue color value of object

Tags: c++, c++11, colors, sfml

```
vector<Text> Game_Text;

Game_Text.push_back(Text("0",Game_Font[0],50));

cout<<Game_Text[0].getFillColor().r<<endl;
```

Using C++11 in Code::Blocks

Nothing it outputted when run, should it not output 255? If `Game_Text[0].getFillColor().r` is replaced with, say, `"test"`, it outputs `test` as normal. No errors, full code is working.

Is it possible to output just a single r/g/b value of an object with this method?

Comment: What type is `Game_Font[0].getFillColor().r`?

Comment: Where does the class Text come from?

Comment: What is `Text`? What does `Text::getFillColor` return? What is `r`? Please try to create a [mcve] to show us. Also please take some time to read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`Color`](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/classsf_1_1Color.php) member [`r`](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/classsf_1_1Color.php#a6a5256ca24a4f9f0e0808f6fc23e01e1) is of the type `Uint8`, which is an alias for `unsigned char`.

And `char` (as well as `signed char` and `unsigned char`, and all aliases based upon these types) are handled as *characters* by the output operator `<<`.

Therefore

```
cout<<Game_Text[0].getFillColor().r<<endl;
```

will attempt to print `r` as a *character*. If its value is not corresponding to a printable character, nothing will seem to be printed.

To print the integer value you need to cast it to an integer-type that is not based on `char`:

```
cout << static_cast<unsigned>(Game_Text[0].getFillColor().r) << '\n';
```